# Send html data from one php page to another

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to send html data like,

```
<div style='padding: 0px; overflow: auto; width: 194px;' id='bar1'><div style='float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 60px'><div style='float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 2px solid #000000; height: 40px;'></div></div></div>
```

from one php page to another.
I have tried doing this via POST but all the div data gets changes to this in the page I am sending the html data to,

```
<div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 20px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 2px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 4px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 2px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 2px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 4px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 2px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 4px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 2px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 2px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 2px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 4px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 2px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 2px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 2px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 2px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 4px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 2px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 2px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 4px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 2px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 2px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 2px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 4px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 2px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 2px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 2px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 4px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 4px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 2px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 2px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 2px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 2px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 2px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 2px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 4px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 4px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 2px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 2px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 4px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 2px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 4px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 2px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 4px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 2px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 2px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 4px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 2px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 2px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 2px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 2px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 2px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 4px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 2px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 2px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 4px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 2px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 4px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 2px\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 2px solid #000000; height: 40px;\'></div><div style=\'float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 40px; width: 20px\'></div><div style=\'clear:both; width: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #000000; text-align: center; font-size: 11px; margin-top: 5px;\'>asdc</div>
```

Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong with this and how can I keep the integrity of the data between the php pages.

EDIT 1:
Code that is sending the data is as follows, (#pdf_data is a textarea)

```
function export_as_pdf2(div_id)
{
            removeAllLinks('remove');
        div_id = 'bar1';
    var content = $('#'+div_id).html();
            content=content.replace(/\"/g,'\'');

    $('#pdf_data').val(content);
    $('#pdf_format_form').submit();
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code that is sending the information via POST, as well as the code that is translating the POST data to HTML?

Comment: function export_as_pdf2(div_id)
{
            removeAllLinks('remove');
        div_id = 'bar1';
 var content = $('#'+div_id).html();
            content=content.replace(/\"/g,'\'');

 $('#pdf_data').val(content);
 $('#pdf_format_form').submit();
}

Comment: I am just using $_REQUEST['variable_name']; How can I convert POST data to HTML??

Comment: have you tried `stripslashes($_REQUEST['variable_name'])` ?

Answer (score 0):

Magic Quote is on in your php.ini settings that's the reason why it's automatically adding slash () to every single quote. Turn off magic quote, as it's good practice. If not, use stripslashes($_POST['post_var']). Don't use $_REQUEST anymore, it's not a good practice.